# AppleScript newbie: trying to create a script that removes all files in a folder that has the word 'alias' in its name

Tags: applescript, keyword-search

I timemachined my new computer, so I can have an easier migration to my new Mac. For some reason, Time Machine decided to make an alias of every single file that is in my downloads folder (I have roughly 300 files), which annoys me to no end.

I tried to make a script that would solve my problem, but I just can't wrap my head around why this doesn't work.

```
try

tell application "Finder"

    delete (every item of folder (path to downloads folder) whose name ends with " alias")

end tell

end try
```

If someone would be able to help me, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Deleting files whose name ends with *" alias"*

To delete files from your Downloads folder whose name ends with *" alias"* use:

```c
tell application "System Events" to delete (files of downloads folder whose name ends with " alias")
```

**Important:** Matching file names ending in *" alias"* doesn't ensure the files to be deleted are true aliases. Any real file(s) could also have a name ending in " alias" - in which case they will be deleted too.

---

#### Deleting files whose kind is "Alias"

To delete real aliases from your Downloads folder consider matching file(s) whose `kind` is `"Alias"` instead.

```c
tell application "System Events" to delete (files of downloads folder whose kind is "Alias")
```

**Note:** This way avoids deleting any real file(s) which could have a name ending in " alias".

Answer (score 0):

The delete command only likes single items, not lists, so can handle it with iteration. Also, use "System Events" when you can for such operations... it's much more stable.
Here's a script that works:

```
set theFolder to (path to downloads folder)

tell application "System Events"
    set itemList to (disk items of downloads folder whose name ends with " alias")
    repeat with thisItem in itemList
        delete thisItem
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with using a `repeat` _loop_ on a _list_ of files to delete them with System Events nonetheless, the System Events `delete` _command_ is quite capable of deleting more than one file at a time without using a `repeat` _loop_, as shown in RobC's answer.

Comment: I did that first and found it unreliable. *shrug*